# How to create a double, triple and quadruple click

Tags: android

I'm trying to find out if the click was double, triple or quadruple. Here is my try:

**Code**

```
// Global variables
private int numberOfTaps;
private long timeMillisOfFirstClick;
private int typeOfClick;
private int interval;

// Inside the on click listener
typeOfClick = (int) SavedData.getValue(requireActivity(), "chipSelected") == R.id.chip_double_click ? 2 : (int) SavedData.getValue(requireActivity(), "chipSelected") == R.id.chip_triple_click ? 3 : 4;
interval = (int) SavedData.getValue(requireActivity(), "chipSelected") == R.id.chip_double_click ? 750 : (int) SavedData.getValue(requireActivity(), "chipSelected") == R.id.chip_triple_click ? 1000 : 1250;
if (numberOfTaps >= typeOfClick)
    numberOfTaps = 1;
else
    numberOfTaps++;
if (numberOfTaps == 1)
    timeMillisOfFirstClick = System.currentTimeMillis();
if (numberOfTaps == typeOfClick && (System.currentTimeMillis() - timeMillisOfFirstClick) <= interval) {
    Log.w("ABC", String.valueOf(typeOfClick));
}
```

The code above sometimes works well and sometimes does not work well. Did I miss something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's working now:

```
typeOfClick = (int) SavedData.getValue(requireActivity(), "chipSelected") == R.id.chip_double_click ? 2 : (int) SavedData.getValue(requireActivity(), "chipSelected") == R.id.chip_triple_click ? 3 : 4;
interval = (int) SavedData.getValue(requireActivity(), "chipSelected") == R.id.chip_double_click ? 750 : (int) SavedData.getValue(requireActivity(), "chipSelected") == R.id.chip_triple_click ? 1000 : 1250;
if (timeMillisOfFirstClick > 0 && (System.currentTimeMillis() - timeMillisOfFirstClick) > interval)
    numberOfTaps = 1;
else
    numberOfTaps++;
if (numberOfTaps == 1)
    timeMillisOfFirstClick = System.currentTimeMillis();
if (numberOfTaps == typeOfClick && (System.currentTimeMillis() - timeMillisOfFirstClick) <= interval)
    Log.w("ABC", String.valueOf(typeOfClick));
```